# <td> width deprecated, how to set the width of a single cell in a row?

Tags: html, css

I want the first cell in a row to be of a certain width, but only that cell, the other cells should vary according to their contents. I would have done this in the markup by specifying width, but I saw it is deprecated and the standards say to use css.

Comment: CSS has a `width` property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I saw it is deprecated and the standards say to use css.

So use CSS!

```
<td style="width: 100px"></td>
```

Or better yet:

```
<!-- in your document head -->
<style type="text/css">
  .width100 {
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>

<!-- in your table -->
<td class="width100"></td>
```

Or even better yet:

```
<style type="text/css">
  td:first-child {
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

There are a lot of ways to express this with CSS but this should give you a starting point.

Comment: he wants this to be applied on first cell, so instead of adding a class i think it's better to use :first-child

Comment: I missed the first cell part. I should update my answer accordingly. +1 to you for pointing that out.

Comment: If you use class, "width100" is not a good name. What happens if you want to change the width to 120? A better name would be for example "column1".

Answer (score 2):

```
tr td:first-child{
width: 100px;
}
```

You must always use css to style html, every style attribute is deprecated.
Except `<td style="width:100px;">` but it's not a good way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a unique class and set the width in CSS.

EXAMPLE:

```
<td class="td-SetWidth"></td>
```

...then in the CSS

```
.td-SetWidth {width: 100px;}
```

Comment: Just FYI... if you care about SEO at all, heavy use of inline styles is discouraged. If you're going to do this multiple times, set a class for the element instead.